# My 3TB seagate external hard drive fell of my 12" high pc onto wooden flooring and now has stopped working, is there anyway to fix it?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, installation, external-hard-drive

Every time I plug it in it sounds like it is starting up but then it sounds like it power downs after 5 seconds or so.

The weird thing is that as soon as it fell to the ground I immediately checked if it was still showing up on my computer, which it was. Then when I awoke the next day it just won't show up anymore.

The light won't turn on nor it will show on my computer. Is there a way to fix the drive or do I just take it for data recovery and hope my stuff is still good? Can I install the external drive into my pc?

I was thinking if I can actually disassemble the drive and see if I can install it directly to my pc, if so is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

It is usually possible - at least with Seagate Expansion drives - to take it apart and connect directly the disk to your computer: it's usually an internal SATA disk connected to an USB adapter.

More often than not, I've found the adapter to be the weakest link. Maybe you're lucky and it really is the adapter's problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it and hope for the best.

Comment: As a matter of curiosity: did it work for you? :)

Answer (score -4):

It's definitely not worth the effort. The drive will never be reliable again, and what good is an unreliable drive?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I'd say the data on the drive, if not backed up, has value.

Comment: While I agree that I wouldn't trust the drive for future use, getting the data off it may absolutely be worth the effort, particularly as the OP appears to be considering resorting to data recovery service companies.

Comment: @Chipperyman The question was, basically, "is there any way to fix it". My answer is "not that's worth the effort". How is that not an answer to the question?